# Вопрос по решению задачки на цикл While и условные операторы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие:

1. Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2. Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново.
3. Если пользователь напишет «exit» или «quit», программа должна быть завершена.

Мой вариант решения:

```
sum1 = 0
while True:
    value = int(input("Введите данные: "))
    sum1 += value
    if value == "sum":
        print("Сумма всех чисел: ", sum1)
    elif value == "exit" or value == "quit":
        break
print("Цикл завершен!")
```

ввожу данные по условию любые:

```
Введите данные: 20
Введите данные: 20
Введите данные: sum
```

выдает ошибку:

```
value = int(input("Введите данные: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sum'
```

в общем понятно, что ругается на строчный тип "sum" который я приравниваю к числовому value, вопрос таков, как мне сделать так чтобы input() принимал и строки, чтобы выполнилась остальная часть кода как положено по условию?

Запутался с типами, так как еще новичок в этом деле, заранее благодарен за разъяснения, ибо в службе поддержки, мне не смогли доступно объяснить.

Comment: Сначала проверьте на ключевые слова, потом, что там не ошибочное слово, а число, потом переведите в число

Comment: Если вместо "sum" поставить число, допустим "0", то все работает if value == 0: так как ноль это число и конфликта типов данных нет.
Введите данные: 20
Введите данные: 20
Введите данные: 0
Сумма всех чисел:  40
Введите данные:
и снова можно вводить данные как задано в условиях задачи, но как сделать так, чтобы input() принимал строку за число и выполнял туже самую задачу, что и с числом?

Answer (score 0):

Он говорит, что не может перевести "sum" в число. Для начала примите строку в строковую переменную, сравните со строкой "sum". Вот когда она не равна sum, вот тогда переводите в число(и то, нужно, если по хорошему, добавить проверку на "число")

Comment: Не совсем вас понял, если можно на примере опишите, что вы имели в виду?

Comment: В вашем случае вы переводите строчку "sum" в тип int(это число!), а это сделать нельзя. Поэтому компилятор ругается

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно проверять является ли значение числом, прежде чем его прибавить.

```
sum1 = 0
while True:
    value = input("Введите данные: ") # Тут убираем перевод в число
    if value.isdigit(): # Сама проверка строки на число
        sum1 += int(value) # Тут его уже переводим
    if value == "sum":
        print("Сумма всех чисел: ", sum1)
    elif value == "exit" or value == "quit":
        break
print("Цикл завершен!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше уже было предложено решение, но можно еще сделать так:

```py
    sum1 = 0
    while True:
        value = input("Введите данные: ")
        if value == "sum":
           print("Сумма всех чисел: ", sum1)
           sum1 = 0
           continue
        elif (value == "exit" or value == "quit"):
           break
        sum1 += int(value)
    print("Цикл завершен!")
```